# App crashes on calling InputStream

Tags: android, inputstream

I am new to Android development.
I am following an online tutorial.
Currently I am learning about threads.

I tried commenting and toasting in the following code to find my error.
I guess the error is in the line `inputStream = connection.getInputStream();`.
If I comment this line and the while loop, the app runs smoothly.

Please help.

```
package com.example.vivzmultithreadingexample;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    private EditText editText;
    private ListView listView;
    private String[] listofImages;
    private ProgressBar progessBar;
    private LinearLayout loadingSection = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.urlList);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        listofImages = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.imageUrls);
        progessBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.downloadProgress);
    }



    public void downloadImage(View v){
        //Toast.makeText(this, "button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Thread myThread = new Thread(new DownloadImagesThread());
        myThread.run();
    }

    public boolean downloadImageUsingThread(String url){


        boolean sucessful = false;
        URL downloadUrl = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection= null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        try {
            downloadUrl = new URL(url);
            connection =(HttpURLConnection) downloadUrl.openConnection();
            inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            int read = -1;
            while((read =inputStream.read()) !=-1){
                L.m(""+read);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            L.m(""+e);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            L.m(""+e);

        }finally{
            if(connection != null){
                connection.disconnect();
            }

            if(inputStream != null){
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    L.m(""+e);
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    }
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, connection.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return sucessful;
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        editText.setText(listofImages[arg2]);

    }

    public class DownloadImagesThread implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            downloadImageUsingThread(listofImages[0]);
            editText.setText(listofImages[0]);


        }
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
08-05 09:52:45.082: D/BstCommandProcessor-Application(1928): Application crash has been observed. 
08-05 09:52:45.082: I/Process(9680): Sending signal. PID: 9680 SIG: 9
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680): Process: com.example.vivzmultithreadingexample, PID: 9680
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3828)
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4443)
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18433)
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680):     ... 11 more
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680):     at com.example.vivzmultithreadingexample.MainActivity.downloadImageUsingThread(MainActivity.java:68)
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680):     at com.example.vivzmultithreadingexample.MainActivity$DownloadImagesThread.run(MainActivity.java:108)
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680):     at com.example.vivzmultithreadingexample.MainActivity.downloadImage(MainActivity.java:48)
08-05 09:52:45.082: E/AndroidRuntime(9680):     ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `myThread.run()` for calling `run()` method this will execute `run()` in thread in which it is called, in your case it is MainThread and Android don't allow network access in MainThread. You have to call `myThread.start()` for stating execution of your thread.

Answer (score 0):

try using these statements under this line

```
connection =(HttpURLConnection) downloadUrl.openConnection();   
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling Network call in main thread,  Use Async Task for that.
Use this code..

```
DownLoadImageTask   downloadImageUsingThread =new DownLoadImageTask ();
downloadImageUsingThread.execute(listofImages[0]);
```

and use all code for downloading image in doInBackground(String... params) method of asyntask and set text in post method.

```
   class DownLoadImageTask  extends Asyntask<String,String,String>{
```

@Override

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
```

// all code goes her

```
 }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result1) {
```

//set text here

}

}

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solution. Just changed `myThread.run()` to `myThread.start()`